# SocketStream timeout not working on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
private async void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
     cts.CancelAfter(1000); // cancel after 1 seconds

     var _socket = new StreamSocket();
     var connectAsync = _socket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("8.8.8.8"), "22",
     SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);

     var connectTask = connectAsync.AsTask(cts.Token);

     await connectTask;   
}
```

Why is the following code not working? Using an advise from other site i was told to create new CancellationTokenSource and set a timeout.

The timeout is not taken into consideration, the code will "block" for around 10-15s then Timeout exception will be triggered instead of 1s.

Any ideas?